# Array not being updated C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm working on this function that takes an an integer as input and is modified by a pointer in the function `pointerArr()`.  `pointerArr()` is supposed to assign a random value to the variable `pointer` and then build an array of the size of `pointer`.  The array is never filled in the loop though.  It is supposed to be filled with the random numbers generated in the loop.  The value of `r` keeps getting updated but the array is never filled.  Any ideas?

```
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int pointerArr(int *pointer);

int main() {
  int pointed = -1;
  pointerArr(&pointed);
  return 0;
}
int pointerArr(int *pointer) {

    int randNum;
    *pointer = 8 + (rand() % (int) (33 - 8 + 1));
    int arr [*pointer];
    for (int i = 0; i < *pointer; i++) {
        int r = rand() % 50;
        arr[i] = r;
    }//
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Use a debugger.

Comment: I've been running through a debugger for a while.  I was able to confirm the array is never filled that way, but I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: `int arr [*pointer];` - that's illegal in standard C++. If you are using an extended/non-standard dialect, you should label your question as such. Formally, your code is not C++.

Comment: `int arr [*pointer];` is a so-called variable length array, because its size isn't known at compile time. It isn't standard C++, it's an extension supported by some compilers such as g++. Why don't you use a `std::vector` instead?

Comment: Could you give me an example of std::vector.  I'm brand new to C++

Comment: @the_martian: How do you know the array is "never filled"? Your code does not output anything from the array.

Comment: @AnT I'm running it through a stepper tool that shows me how the code runs.

Comment: @the_martian: Well, maybe it is your stepper tool that's displaying misleading information? If your code compiles (re invalid array declaration), then "never filling" array is what one'd call "magical" behavior which is rather hard to believe.

Comment: @the_martian Your code runs fine on ideone: http://ideone.com/4NBJFd. I've just added the <iostream> header for `cout`, and another loop after yours that prints the content of the array (I could have added it into your loop, but I wanted to leave it untouched).

Comment: @AnT: I'm running the code through Python Visualizer with the C++ compiler option selected.  I've never had problems with them before, but if you want to take a look I would appreciate it.

Comment: @FabioTurati Interesting.  That's reassuring.  Also ideone is cool.  Thanks for showing that to me.

Comment: Possibly, this was compiled with optimizations on, which recognize that you never used `arr` and just got rid of it completely. If you add in `cout` statements to print the array, you're now using it, so the compiler no longer gets rid of it.

Comment: Not sure which compiler you're using, but try finding out how to disable optimization, and see if it still does it.

Comment: Pass `int &n` instead of `int* pointer`
Use `vector` and `generate_n` to make it more concise
`std::vector<int> arr;`
`std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(arr), n, []{return rand() % 50; });` http://ideone.com/zew1IZ

Comment: As mentioned above, you can't define an array with a variable size, it's illegal in C++. Moreover what is the point of this statement `*pointer = 8 + (rand() % (int) (33 - 8 + 1));`, why don't you just make it `*pointer = 8 + (rand() % (int) 26);` ?